# Notepad++ - Find list of acronyms in text file

Tags: notepad++, regex

I want to make list of acronyms in a text file.

I tried some regex to find the list of words with all capital letters.
Ex. `[A-Z]+`

This did not work.

I also have another problem. Some acronyms do not have all capital letters.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a regex to find words with more than one capital letter?
2. Is there a way to return all the words enclosed in brackets ?

Example:

> Just an example (one) script (two)

Expected output:

> one two

Comment: What is a "word" for you? Only alphabetics? Alphanumerics? Word character class `[A-Za-z0-9_]`? Alphanumerics with non latin characters? Everything that is not a space or punctuation? Something else?

Comment: For your second question, do you want to match word inside parenthesis or remove everything that is not inside parenthesis?

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression to find a word with more than one capital letter:

```
\b\w*[A-Z]\w*[A-Z]\w*\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/X4xKbb/1/)

Regex101 is pretty good in explaining what each part of the regex does, but let me know if something is unclear.

When using case-sensitive regexes like this, be sure to enable the 'Match case' option:

[image]

---

A regular expression to find a word enclosed in brackets:

```
\(\w+\)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JQzJ29/1/)

Note that since `(` and `)` are special characters in regex, they need to be escaped.

Comment: hello. In notepad++, your first regex example `\b\w*[A-Z]\w*[A-Z]\w*\b`  selects all "test" variants, in case I want to make a replacement. Should selects and replace only one or two ?

Comment: @JustMe I'm not completely following you, but I think you have to enable the 'Match case' option (see the edited answer). I didn't realize it was disabled by default.

Comment: great, thanks a lot.